# FLEXNET LICENCING ERROR :-15,10

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab R2013b and I need to configure flexnet licence manager. I have the licence **.dat** and **.lic** files. I have tried many times to configure but I keep getting this flexnet error message:

> [Detecting lmgrd processes...] License server status: 78@user
>       License file(s) on user: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\licenses\license.dat:
>
> lmgrd is not running: Cannot connect to license server system.  The
>   license server manager (lmgrd) has not been started yet,  the wrong
>   port@host or license file is being used, or the  port or hostname in
>   the license file has been changed. Server name:   127.0.0.1 License
>   path:  78@user; FLEXnet Licensing error:-15,10.  System Error: 10061
>   "WinSock: Connection refused" For further information, refer to the
>   FLEXnet Licensing documentation, available at
>   "www.flexerasoftware.com".

Please, any ideas what exactly I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Is the flexnet server running on the same machine? If so, verify that the server is running and that the firewall has an exception set.

Comment: Daniel, well I don't know how to verify that let alone exception set. Will do some research and let you know of my attempt. Thank you.